# Retrieving wrong date while fetching Date from oracle mybatis 3

Tags: mybatis

I am currently using Mybatis 3.3.1 and Oracle 11g.
We have a date column in table which store value in format of 'DD-MON-YY', example '15-FEB-2016'.
On java side I have java.sql.Date variable to store the same.

Now when I execute the select statement and Mybatis maps the date to java variable it is being retrieved as '3916-02-15'.
please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance,
Pankaj

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. Oracle itself gives me a wrong value. When I select the date with different format with YYYY then it converts the 16 to 3916. Please help me to solve this problem.